# Error Loading related entities on demand (entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty())

Tags: breeze

I am doing a application using durandaljs and breezejs. I am trying to get the value of a Navigation Properties. My problem is that when I tryied to call this method in breeze:

```
user.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty("userType");
```

I get the error ""The 'propertyOrExpr' parameter  must be a 'string'"". This error is throw for the follow section of code:

```
var q = new EntityQuery(navProperty.entityType.defaultResourceName);
var pred = buildNavigationPredicate(entity, navProperty);
q = q.where(pred);
```

The problem is that 'pred' is empty, because 'buildNavigationPredicate' return null. Getting into the 'buildNavigationPredicate':

```
if (navigationProperty.foreignKeyNames.length === 0) return null;
```

The problem is that the 'foreignKeyNames' array is empty, all the rest field in the 'navigationProperty' are filled, but I don't know why, but my server doesn't send this information. (Also the foreignKeyNamesServer is empty).

Do somebody have the same problem? can be it a bug of breeze?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution yesterday and I din't have time to refresh this. The problem was in the definition of my user class. I am using Web API and EF Code first. My old user class was:

```
    public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set;}
}
```

To do work the user.loadNavigationProperty('userType'), I had to change the old user class in this:

```
    public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public Guid UserType_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserType_Id")]
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set;}
}
```

And doing that, I solved the problem. However, I can implement this solution for many to many relations. Doing a little of research, I have discovered, that Many to Many relations are not supported currently for breeze. 
So the only thing that I can do is implement a middle entity in many to many relation.

Very thanks Ward for your time. If there are any other way to solve that problem, I would be very pleased to listen. Thanks.

Comment: Until EF lets you supplement its conventions there is no alternative known to me. Humans mentally erase the underscore (_) in `UserType_Id`; EF does not. Had the property been named UserTypeId, EF would have found it.  Btw, if you don't want database-oriented attributes in your model class code (I know I don't), you can use the EF fluent API to help EF understand your model.

Comment: We know that some people want Breeze to support many-to-many. There's a User Voice item for it. I hope people give up on that request and that we never implement it. We will have to *if you all really want it*. But I think it is a terrible idea ... as [I have explained elsewhere on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902352/breeze-js-error-collection-navigation-properties-may-not-be-set). Go with the intermediate entity and be grateful ... for the day will come when you are glad that you did.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer. I am using Fluent Api; however I thought that it would be easier to explain my solution using annotations. Regarding to the many to many relation, I can see you point; I will implement the intermediate entity. Thanks, it has helped me to clarify a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not helpful. Fortunately, you've traced the problem to the lack of foreignKeyNames. That suggests that you are missing something in the definition of the navigation property. For some reason, Breeze isn't detecting that the FK property in `User` that relates it to a `UserType`. If you are using Web API and EF, you might confirm that the FK is properly specified on the server.

Actually, to help properly, we'd have to see your class definition of `User`, the portion of the metadata from the server that describes `User` and `UserType` (**PLEASE DO NOT print the entire metadata!**) and a snapshot of the `EntityType` object returned at runtime from `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('User')`

Comment: Hello Ward, thanks for your help. I have found a solution by my own. However I would like to know why I have to do that to solve the problem. And if there are any different way to solve the problem, and also any way to solve the many to many reltaion problem. Thanks

Comment: I'll comment/explain on your answer