# Association Table data with breeze and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-5, breeze

I have a entity framework database first set up and I'm having issues getting data from a table EF treats as an association because it's basically a navigation property.  I have a Survey table with an EventId(PK), FacilityId, ExitDate, and Status.  I also have a SurveyCategories table with CategoryID(PK), Description and a SurvCat table that just has SurveyId and CategoryId as foreign keys.  I can get data from other related tables that don't use a middle table like SurvCat, but even following the documentation from the breeze site for navigation properties I cannot get anything loaded into the SurveyCategories array in each Survey object.  I checked the metadata and it's showing the navigation property but I get nothing with this code:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Surveys')
            .where("facilityId", "eq", whereClause)
            .skip(currentPage * 5).take(5)
            .expand("Facility")
            .expand("SurveyCategories")
            .expand("SurveyCite")
            .expand("SurveyDL")
            .orderBy(orderBy.survey)
            .inlineCount(true);
```

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer for this other question can help you tu solve the problem: [Error Loading related entities on demand (entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145547/error-loading-related-entities-on-demand-entityaspect-loadnavigationproperty).

The N to N relations are not supported in breeze, so you have to use a intermediate entity to do work this.